# How to make a systemctl unit (or service) start with system (on boot)

Tags: linux, service, debian, systemd

I have these options on my .service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Atualizador de Sincronizacao

[Service]
TimeoutStartSec=0
ExecStart=/opt/sn_home/sincronizador/bin/jarupdater.sh
```

but it does not start with the system (like sshd does, for instance) so I need to run a "systemctl start" command every time.

**What option do I need to add in this unit so it starts with the system?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Required the `[Install]` section on this unit where I added a `WantedBy=multi-user.target` so the service would start when the system starts.

Finally I had to enable the unit with the command that Marshall Whittaker gave me:

```
systemctl enable myservice.service
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
systemctl enable yourservice
```

Comment: I didn't know you could do that, thanks. I'm not impressed with the word selection by the devs thoguh. I mean how does 'enable' implies that this service will run on boot?